constexpr vs constexpr inline vs define - Optimizing generic utility functions in C and C++
I have a simple function that I compile for C in my operating code and for C++ in my tests. Since I'll use this function extensively in my code, I'd like to declare it in a utility file and make it as efficient as possible.
Let's consider an example function that calculates the absolute difference between two uint64_t values.
Here are three options:
Option 1:
constexpr uint64_t diff(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}

In C++, this function will be evaluated at compile time and implicitly inlined.
In C, constexpr will be ignored, implying only that the return value of the function is constexpr.
Option 2:
constexpr inline uint64_t diff(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}

In C++, this function will be evaluated at compile time and implicitly inlined. The inline keyword is redundant.
In C, constexpr will be ignored, implying only that the return value of the function is constexpr, and there is a hint to the compiler to switch the function with its body.
Option 3:
#define DIFF(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? ((a) - (b)) : ((b) - (a)))

In C++, it works, but using a constexpr function can add type safety.
In C, it works, and it's probably the most efficient way, as in an inline function, the compiler might ignore inline.
Which choice is better, and why? is there a fourth option?
Remember that I need to pick up the best choice for both c and c++.

Re: "that I compile for C in my operating code and for C++ in my tests": That seems unwise to me. As you're clearly aware, C and C++ are not the same language, and they have some real differences. So the function in your production code and the function in your tests are different functions, even if they have the same source code.

constexpr functions are implicitly inline, so (2) is just a more verbose version of (1). Are you worried about just release build performance, or debug performance too? Did you compare the resulting assembly? The compiler should be able to execute the function at compile-time even without constexpr if the body is visible, so you can just make a static function in the header (which AFAIK is the only sane way to have function definitions in headers in C), and avoid any #ifdef __cplusplus hassle.

BTW, the macro version will evaluate its arguments twice, which can sometimes be very bad.

(And you should probably trust your compiler more: if it ignores inline in a given case, it probably has a good reason!)

DIFF evaluates a and b multiple times. If those are non-const expressions and not simple variables, an inline function will be more efficient even if it were not inlined.  If the expressions have side effects the result may even be incorrect.

Add [[gnu::always_inline]] or __attribute__((always_inline))  to the second one.

Option3 is the worst. Function like macros have tendency to introduce strange bugs.

inline doesn't inline anything, it only allows multiple definitions in different files. Apart from that, compilers can inline functions with and without inline. That said, the macro is not just not typesafe, but if you have an expression that causes side effects, that expression is evaluated more than once, which I consider more grave. Lastly, let me ask you a question: Have you measured the performance impact of that function? If not, what you're doing is called "premature optimization". Stay with the clearest version until you know you need something more complex.

inline today means something else then force inline code. It just indicates that definition of function may appear multiple times.

constexpr is mostly irrelevant unless you need to use the result somewhere constexpr is strictly needed (like as an integer template value). if you call diff with values of a and b that aren't known at compile-time then you shouldn't delude yourself into thinking that it's magically evaluated at compile-time.

@UlrichEckhardt inline does act as a hint, making the function more likely to be inlined. See: Do compilers take inline as a hint?

Can you explain why must you use C for production and C++ for testing ? Using a different language for testing (with specific differences in the area you want to test) doesn't sound like a good idea.

Imagine DIFF(x++, foo(y));

The ideal option is something you haven't yet mentioned:
/* constexpr in C++ */ static inline uint64_t diff(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}

Note that only variables can be constexpr in C, not functions.
The reason why we need static inline for C is that inline works differently in C (see also Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99?). It merely lets you provide an inline definition, but if the function doesn't actually get inlined (such as on a debug build), you would get a linker error without also declaring it extern inline somewhere.
static inline circumvents this problem and lets you define everything in a header with internal linkage.
It's dirty (because N copies of this function exist, and don't necessarily get merged), but it works.
In C++, static inline is legal, albeit a bit redundant.
constexpr makes a function an inline function already (see Does constexpr imply inline?) and we don't need this workaround with static, so you could also write:
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define INLINE_UTILITY constexpr
#else
#define INLINE_UTILITY static inline
#endif
#define

INLINE_UTILITY uint64_t diff(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}

Another legal option is to simply define the function static in both C and C++, but then you lose constexpr in C++ and the inlining hint to the optimizer might be slightly weaker (although in practice, this is likely irrelevant).
Option 3 is definitely the worst. Macros are very fragile and hard to get right, and yours would evaluate a and b multiple times.

I would still make it static constexpr in C++ to prevent weird ODR interactions with C parts linked to C++ parts. Then you could write static inline CONSTEXPR_IN_CXX uint64_t diff (and maybe have it be [[unsequenced]]/[[gnu::__const__]] in C)

@Artyer C parts cannot get linked to C parts anyway unless you use extern "C". Also, since diff is static in C, every C TU has its own definition and would have no need to link against some external C++ definition. static in headers is a potential source of other ODR violations in C++, namely if you take the address of diff, which would be different in different headers.

[[unsequenced]] would be valid here, but because the definition of diff is always visible and diff will almost certainly be inlined with optimizations enabled, it's not very useful. You really only need [[unsequenced]] for when definitions aren't visible.
